# Idiom for a student being purposely overly verbose only to make an essay look longer

Tags: idioms, idiom-request

Your teacher assigns you an essay and you write down anything that can be said about the subject.

You are satisfied, but the word count doesn't reach the required minimum.

So you use lousy tricks like substituting "in other words" with "to put it another way", and generally rewriting each sentence in the most verbose way possible without increasing the conveyed concepts.

Bingo: the essay is much worse than before but it's now "long enough".

In Italian we use the ***derogatory*** idiom "allungare la brodaglia" which can be literally translated by "to water down the broth" or "to water down the slop" meaning to increase the use of unnecessary words to make the essay look longer but without adding any concept to it.

Is there an equivalent ***derogatory*** idiom in English?

---

So far I only found "to stretch out the meeting" to mean "to talk and talk in order to make the meeting longer than necessary".

In my case can I use "to stretch out the essay" or "to stretch out the slop" to mean "to add unnecessary words to the essay with the only purpose of increasing the word count, even at the expense of the readability of the essay"?

Any other idiom suggested?

Comment: Since your alias looks like a combination of "_Futuroma_" and "_The Simpsons_": American Dad, Season 1, Episode 1, 13:20 in.

Comment: I would say that he's writing "like he's paid by the word".

Comment: related (padding out letters instead of words): "sesquipedalian loquaciousness"

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that "to water something down" is an English idiom. It usually means to make an idea or something less forceful. But I would say it would not apply to your specific case of "adding extra words to make an essay less concise/clear and therefore worse".

Comment: Are you looking for a gender specific word?  Do schoolgirls not do this too?

Comment: The answer is padding or padded.

Comment: @mcalex I was looking for conciseness of the title...  Anyway, if you are willing to suggest a gender neutral term which conveys the exact meaning of "schoolboy/schoolgirl" I'm ready to learn. I excluded "pupil" and "scholar" because as far as I can see from my dictionary they refer to an oldest age and higher level of education, and it would have been out of the context I meant.- Forgive me, but it's not easy for a non native speaker living in a non English speaking country to stay up-to-date with political correctness. So suggestions may be useful, rhetorical question are NOT.

Comment: @FrySimpson Schoolchild is appropriate here.

Comment: @catherine does not schoolchild refer to under their teens? ---- [ In Italian school I was taught so, and that "children" can be used as gender neutral just to mean both sons and daughters irrelative to their age, but in all other contexts a child is definitely under 13... - I don't have any full immersion experience to say if this is true or if it was true 30+ years ago but now the frantic search for gender neutral terms has expanded the age boundaries of "child" even in "schoolchild" --- surely in Italy a 15 yo would get mad if referred as "bambino/a" the literal translation of "child" ]

Comment: unfortunately I was in elementary school before the internet was popular (high school it didn't matter much as I had gotten rid of any essay course by then except English which unfortunately was still required). Why? because essays are *a lot* of work. Especially when you haven't read the source material, which of course I never did. I would say nowadays it is probably best to find a synopsis somewhere on the internet - that way you can get the best of both worlds, not read the book but know what you're writing about... and then this problem just goes away on its own.

Comment: Seems like a new word emerged: ChatGPT.

Comment: The classic example is “The very very very end”.

Comment: @FrySimpson 'student' would be my first choice.  I believe 'pupil' would also work fine.  What age is your context, if under 13 is too young, but higher education is too old?  In any event, I would use pupil for primary (grade) school to high school, student for high school and university/college, and scholar for university onwards.  I wasn't being rhetorical, I originally thought you *were* talking about male students only.  Also, schoolboys, schoolgirls, and schoolchildren are all the same age.  Idiomatically bambino/a doesn't translate to *child*, it translates to boy/girl.

Comment: My grandmother did this on a college essay in the 1940s.  The professor wrote at the top: "Diarrhea of words and constipation of thought"

Comment: @mcalex I went with "student". I'm not very familiar with terms like high school vs college vs university, since here the educational systems is different. We go from "scuola superiore" (14 to 19 yo) to "università" (19 to 23 or 24 yo). We don't have a thing such as college in between. - Anyway what I was thinking of was an age range more or less of teenagers, not under teen, not over teen. - I thought that "boy/girl" was the term for such a range, while "child" was more appropriate for under teens. - Maybe there's not a way to express in English the same nuance I have in my mind in Italian

Comment: I was trying to be verbose as I'm sort of aware of the differences but probably just added to the confusion. In Au our high (or secondary) school seems close to scuola superiore except more 12-17 than 14-19.  I used college as I figured others were familiar with it - here it's generally synonymous with university, but can also be high school.  It seems to be secondary school in the US.  Boy/girl are equal to male/female child.  All those ages are the same.  Though when used as 'not adult' child goes up to the legal definition (18 or 21 usu).  Student is good.  :-D

Comment: I don't know that it's what you are looking for, but your 'water down the broth' explanation makes me think of the US '[hamburger helper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_Helper)' product.  It's not a known idiom, but you could explore something like "the essay is more hamburger-helper than meat" which would generally be understood, even outside of US.  In the music industry it's called 'filler, all those tracks on the album that you skip or program out of the playlist.

Comment: @mcalex thanks, this metaphor can come handy in another occasion. What i was looking for is an equivalent idiom of the Italian "allungare la brodaglia". - In most cases there are equivalent idioms between Italian and English eg "costa un occhio" is equivalent to "it costs an arm and a leg" (literally "an eye"), "piove a catinelle" = "it's raining cats and frogs", etc. - So I assumed that some equivalent idiom existed in this case too, but since after 5k views and many answers/comments no exact equivalent has been written, I think in this case it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 46):

I would describe the process as **inflating** or **padding** my essay.

I might call the extra words and phrases I add **fluff**.

Comment: "Padding" could also be used here (for the action as well as the unnecessary material). [Longman definition](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/padding): "unnecessary and uninteresting details or words that are added to make a sentence, speech etc longer – used to show disapproval"

Comment: I agree and I added it to my answer. If this comment is not sufficient attribution, I can note it in the answer itself that it came from you.

Comment: Thanks to @nschneid 's comment I found that the verb is **pad (something) out**. Example: *"Don’t pad out your answer to make it seem impressive"* from [this definition](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/pad) (see **pad² verb** meaning **4**)

Comment: I think that the idiomatic usage would be "Don't pad your answer" (that is, without the word "out" from "pad out" as suggested.

Answer (score 6):

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/waffle)

**waffle** <sup>2</sup> /*informal, mainly* British /

*verb*
<sup>1</sup> (intr often foll by on) to speak or write in a vague and wordy manner: *he waffled on for hours*

*noun*
<sup>2</sup> vague and wordy speech or writing

Comment: Side note: In the US, "waffle" has a completely different meaning. (Aside from the literal definition of a pancake-like food one eats for breakfast ...) It means to be vague about one's position or to change one's position to suit whatever is popular at the moment. Often used of politicians, as in, "Senator Jones has really waffled on gun control. When he's in Massachusetts he sounds like he's pro-gun control, but when he's in Texas he's against it."

Comment: @jay that would be flip-flopping. Waffling would be refusing to give  clear answer.

Comment: Outstanding!  Also, I disagree there would be confusion for American readers.  Sure, waffle has a number of senses; as does 100% of words in English.

Comment: @Jay I've always thought the politicians were using the wrong breakfast food for that analogy.  It should be *pancakes* - which, unlike waffles, have to be flipped while cooking.

Comment: waf·fle
[ˈwäfəl]
VERB
NORTH AMERICAN
fail to make up one's mind:
"Joseph had been waffling over where to go"
BRITISH
speak or write, especially at great length, without saying anything important or useful:
"he waffled on about everything that didn't matter"

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Years ago I heard a comedian joke that some politician, "has waffled so much on the issues because his major campaign contributor is House of Pancakes".

Answer (score 5):

It's on the vulgar side, but in college we used the term *bullshitting* to convey this exact meaning.  One who was particularly skilled in it was a *bullshit artist.*

Comment: This usage is popular in Europe in university and professional contexts too. In my mind "bullshitting" also encompasses the use of buzzwords the intended audience likes. However, that meaning is a little different since the challenge with college texts and professional texts is typically to stay *below* a maximum word count.

Comment: This doesn't have the same meaning to me (not in English at least).

Comment: I had a teacher tell us that if we needed help making it to the assigned page/word length that we should BS - Be Specific.

Comment: In the US, I take this to mean lies and/or nonsense, not honest, accurate information presented using more words than necessary.  Also I believe that it’s more commonly applied to speech than to writing.  See [American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=bullshit), [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bullshit) and [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/bullshit_2)

Comment: An alternative to *bullshit artist* could be *bullshit merchant*, or simply *bullshitter*

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of any commonly-used idiom. If I wanted to express this idea, I would probably say, "unnecessarily verbose", or simply "wordy".

There is the informal phrase, "padded out", or "padded out with fluff", which you might consider an idiom. But that's usually used to mean, not that each sentence includes more words than necessary, but that unnecessary extra material has been included. Like the student was assigned to write a paper about the assassination of Julius Caesar and he couldn't make it long enough, so he threw in irrelevant discussion of the Punic Wars.

Comment: Ah!  Padded!  Brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

[Purple Prose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purple_prose) is a related idiom, that is definitely critical or derogatory.

It's not specifically aimed at inflated length, but there is significant crossover.

Comment: When purple prose is longer than ordinary speech, it's to allow florid metaphors, elaborate paraphrase, and long words, not to pad out.

Comment: As I said, it's a related and overlapping, though distinct, concept.
It is entirely possible for the intent to include achieving a greater length, especially for a writing project, since it's (slightly) easier to defend as authorial voice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is an idiom that is an exact match, but a few similar phrases come to mind. (Perhaps with a British slant.)

- "Alice only had one original idea in her essay, but she **milked it for all it was worth**." - (over)use something to the point of exhaustion.
- "Boris hadn't prepared for the exam, but he wrote **four pages of waffle** and hoped for the best."
- "Caroline's approach to essay-writing was simple: **never use one word where a dozen might do**." (Or any other number >1 instead of 'a dozen'!)
- "Darren's essay focussed on **quantity over quality**." (An unfavorable contrast with the more common phrase, 'quality over quantity').

Answer (score 1):

"Padding", "puffing up", "pencil whipping", "glorifying", "bullshitting", "bloviating" and "inflating" all work equally well.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps "to over-egg the pudding". EDIT: It's not used solely for writing, however. It would suggest writing that is overly flowery rather than full of superfluous words. Which I guess is the opposite of watering down... It rather depends on what kind of words are being added to lengthen the essay.

"to stretch out the essay" > Yes.
"to stretch out the slop" > No.

Comment: Is this a British English set phrase? As an American i have no idea what it means...

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas This is UK English but sounds very ''literary'' or ''artistic'', like you might refer to a writer who was well-known for over-egging the pudding ie. being too flowery and extravagant with their novel writing.

Comment: "over-egging the pudding" is a little too vague here, I think. It means something close to "going too far in an otherwise reasonable direction"; overdoing it; trying much too hard and so messing up. But if an essay is padded with waffle then the argument may well not be over-egged, but watered down. But if, say, a writer goes on from describing a minor, relatable annoyance on public transport to advocating the guillotine for the perpetrators and merely for the sake of additional column-inches, then certainly they have lost the reader by over-egging for the sake of word count.

Answer (score 0):

**Slipslop**, while labeled *archaic* in the [Merriam-Webster entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slipslop), seems to be a good fit. It even contains *slop* from your translation.

The concrete meaning is indeed "watery food". The second meaning in the  dictionary entry is "shallow talk or writing", which comes close to fluff or padding.

I should add that I didn't know that word before I encountered it as one of the translations for *Gelaber* [in LEO](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/gelaber).

Comment: Writing that is slipslop is bad prose, it is meaningless and careless i.e. "sloppy" without substance or a clear idea.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Well, it's the text equivalent of watery soup. That's what you get by adding water to a good soup or insubstantial words to a good text.

Comment: If  someone's accuses a piece of writing as being slipslop they are not criticising its length or how much of it is redundant. They are saying it is clumsily and shoddily written.

Answer (score 0):

The word **Verbiage** means exactly this:

> a profusion of words usually of little or obscure content

- Mirriam-Webster Dictionary

> language that is very complicated and contains a lot of unnecessary words

- Cambridge Dictionary

> If you refer to someone's speech or writing as verbiage, you are critical of them because they use too many words, which makes their speech or writing difficult to understand.

- Collins Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

How about "**beating around the bush**?"

It means "discuss a matter without coming to the point." (definition from Google)

> To my dismay, the author beat around the bush instead of writing a
> clear, concise essay.

> He never beat around the bush when something was annoying him.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/beat-around-the-bush

Comment: I think that "beating around the bush" is more avoiding the point because you are embarrassed to talk about it (and thus more relevant to speech than to writing) rather than adding useless words to make the writing longer. - If the subject is "Have you ever stolen?" and the plain an simple answer is "Once I stole an apple": if I say "My family is very poor, I don't always have enough to eat..." I am *beating around the bush*, while if I say "In one day which date I cannot remember I stole a round fruit called apple" I am *padding*, or *stretching*, or *inflating* as some answers pointed out.